# Make quadrilateral curves the exact size of the faces they are on in geometry nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I guess that I can get an area of each face by using "face area" node but what I do not understand is how to use this information. I need each point to have the exact size of the faces they are on. These points are distributed on faces by using "mesh to points" node, then I'm telling the system that I want them to be on a certain faces and making them rotate correctly, these all work. But there is a problem, I don't understand how to make my point sized correctly, my points are representing quadrilaterals, the curves, with the size that I can control in editor.

My idea was to use "capture attribute" node and then plug it into "scale" socket of "instance on points" node, but then I realized that I can't do that, because I have the height and width of a curve and I'm just evenly scaling it, this is definitely not the right way of doing this

[image: nodes]

Comment: I don't suppose generating the items _from_ the faces is an option?

Comment: It's an option now, I have found what I wanted, it's a "transfer attribute" node

Comment: Or... Split edges, convert to curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

### Variant 1

If you have instantiated the quadrilateral curves at the faces, you only need to transfer the positions of the *Face Corners* of the original mesh to the points of the curves:

[image]

### Variant 2

As *@RobinBetts* correctly mentioned, this can also be solved by directly converting the faces of the mesh to curves:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>